# How to create a shiny logo like Google Chromebooks website

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://www.google.com/chromebook/#features

When you hover the logo, you can see a shiny animation.
I have looked into the source code but it doesn't look like done with :hover

any idea about how they do it?
Thank you very much

Comment: It is inappropriate to ask this type of questions in this type of website

Comment: I'm sorry about it. First time here.

Comment: Then you dont downvote, you request it be moved to the appropriate stack exchange site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's using the CHEDDAR Canvas Animation Framework by Eric Lee.  Cheddar is based off of Cake.js by Ilmari Heikkinen http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/

This file : http://www.gstatic.com/chromebook/js/third_party/chromeicons-main.min.js

Answer (score 3):

Look at the HTML source. It's done using a `<canvas>`.

```
 <div id="header-logo"> 
      <noscript>
          <a data-g-label="MAIN-NAV-HOME" href="index.html" id="header-logo-noscript">
              <img alt="Chrome" src="static/images/chromelogo-124x34.png">
          </a>
      </noscript>
      <canvas height="40" id="canvas-logo" width="123">
          <a data-g-label="MAIN-NAV-HOME" href="index.html">
              <img alt="Chrome" src="static/images/chromelogo-124x34.png">
          </a>
      </canvas> 
</div>
```

The relevant script appears to be [`chromeicons-main.min.js`](http://www.gstatic.com/chromebook/js/third_party/chromeicons-main.min.js).

Answer (score 0):

It's done with a [canvas element](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html&ei=9XD7TZrbOJGChQfVpMm1Aw&usg=AFQjCNH3dOxoMBzssYO6XEBsbWs9SxPSRA).

Answer (score 0):

Firebug says it's a canvas, which means HTML5.

The script http://www.gstatic.com/chromebook/js/third_party/chromeicons-main.min.js appears to contain a "canvas animation framework" that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you look sources, you will see they use CHEDDAR Canvas Animation Framework to animate this logo.

Answer (score 0):

looks like some canvas stuff to me. (nice beginner [tutorial here](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/))

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the relevant portion of [chromeicons-main.min.js](http://www.gstatic.com/chromebook/js/third_party/chromeicons-main.min.js). for the chrome logo itself.

```
ChromeLogo = CClass(CanvasNode, {
    center_gradient: new Gradient({
        type: "radial",
        startX: 7,
        startY: -7,
        endRadius: 14,
        colorStops: [
            [1, "#005791"],
            [0.62, "#2284DC"],
            [0, "#86B9E2"]
        ]
    }),
    center_back: new Gradient({
        type: "radial",
        endRadius: 14,
        colorStops: [
            [0, "#D2D2D2"],
            [1, "#FFFFFF"]
        ]
    }),
    top_gradient: new Gradient({
        type: "radial",
        endRadius: 16,
        colorStops: [
            [0.15, "#F37C65"],
            [1, [243, 124, 90, 0]]
        ]
    }),
    highlight_gradient3: new Gradient({
        type: "radial",
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        endRadius: 40,
        colorStops: [
            [1, "rgba(255,255,255,0)"],
            [0.4, "rgba(255,255,255,.4)"],
            [0, "rgba(255,255,255,0)"]
        ]
    }),
    highlight_gradient4: new Gradient({
        type: "radial",
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        endRadius: 8,
        colorStops: [
            [1, "rgba(255,255,255,0)"],
            [0.4, "rgba(255,255,255,.5)"],
            [0, "rgba(255,255,255,0)"]
        ]
    }),
    highlight_gradient5: new Gradient({
        type: "radial",
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        endRadius: 8,
        colorStops: [
            [1, "rgba(255,255,255,0)"],
            [0.5, "rgba(255,255,255,.9)"],
            [0, "rgba(255,255,255,0)"]
        ]
    }),
    initialize: function () {
        CanvasNode.initialize.call(this);
        this.scale = 0.78;
        this.catchMouse = false;
        this.textGlow = new Circle(30, {
            fill: this.highlight_gradient5,
            x: 22,
            y: 23,
            zIndex: 2
        });
        this.append(this.textGlow);
        this.center = new Circle(7.5, {
            fill: this.center_gradient,
            x: 22,
            y: 23,
            zIndex: 4,
            clip: true
        });
        this.centerBack = new Circle(9, {
            fill: this.center_back,
            x: 22,
            y: 23,
            zIndex: 3
        });
        this.border = new CanvasNode({
            zIndex: 2
        });
        this.mask = new CanvasNode({
            x: 22,
            y: 23
        });
        this.ch3 = new Circle(8, {
            fill: this.highlight_gradient4,
            scale: 0.1,
            opacity: 0,
            compositeOperation: "lighter"
        });
        this.center.append(this.ch3);
        this.red = _iconController.asset("logo_red");
        this.red.childNodes[0].clip = true;
        this.red.setProps({
            x: -17,
            y: -20,
            clip: true
        });
        this.redShadow = _iconController.asset("shadow_red");
        this.redShadow.setProps({
            x: -17,
            y: -13,
            zIndex: 2
        });
        this.rh3 = new Circle(40, {
            fill: this.highlight_gradient3,
            scale: 0.1,
            opacity: 1,
            compositeOperation: "lighter",
            x: 17,
            y: 20,
            zIndex: 4
        });
        this.red.childNodes[0].append(this.rh3);
        this.yellow = _iconController.asset("logo_yellow");
        this.yellow.setProps({
            x: -1.5,
            y: -9
        });
        this.yellow.childNodes[0].clip = true;
        this.yellowShadow = _iconController.asset("shadow_yellow");
        this.yellowShadow.setProps({
            zIndex: 2,
            x: 1,
            y: -9
        });
        this.yh3 = new Circle(40, {
            fill: this.highlight_gradient3,
            scale: 0.1,
            opacity: 1,
            compositeOperation: "lighter",
            x: 1.5,
            y: 9,
            zIndex: 4
        });
        this.yellow.childNodes[0].append(this.yh3);
        this.green = _iconController.asset("logo_green");
        this.green.setProps({
            x: -20,
            y: -11
        });
        this.green.childNodes[0].clip = true;
        this.greenShadow = _iconController.asset("shadow_green");
        this.greenShadow.setProps({
            x: -2,
            y: 5,
            zIndex: 2
        });
        this.gh3 = new Circle(40, {
            fill: this.highlight_gradient3,
            scale: 0.1,
            opacity: 1,
            compositeOperation: "lighter",
            x: 20,
            y: 11.5,
            zIndex: 4
        });
        this.green.childNodes[0].append(this.gh3);
        this.top = new Circle(19, {
            fill: false,
            clip: true,
            x: 24,
            y: 23,
            zIndex: 5
        });
        this.topGrad = new Circle(19, {
            fill: this.top_gradient,
            x: -2,
            y: -24
        });
        this.mask.append(this.red, this.redShadow, this.yellow, this.yellowShadow, this.green, this.greenShadow);
        this.border.append(this.mask);
        this.top.append(this.topGrad);
        this.append(this.border, this.centerBack, this.center, this.top);
        this.text = _iconController.asset("logo_text");
        this.text.setProps({
            x: 49,
            y: 8
        });
        for (var a = 0; a < this.text.childNodes[0].childNodes.length; a++) {
            this.text.childNodes[0].childNodes[a].opacity = 1
        }
        this.append(this.text)
    },
    mouseOver: function () {
        this.canvas.play();
        _tw.removeTweensOf([this.textGlow, this.rh3, this.yh3, this.gh3, this.ch3]);
        this.textGlow.scale = this.ch3.scale = this.rh3.scale = this.gh3.scale = this.yh3.scale = 0.1;
        this.textGlow.opacity = this.rh3.opacity = this.gh3.opacity = this.yh3.opacity = 1;
        var a = new Array(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3);
        var b = shuffle(a);
        _tw.addTween(this.center, {
            time: 0.1,
            scale: 1.02,
            transition: "easeOutQuad"
        });
        _tw.addTween(this.centerBack, {
            time: 0.1,
            scale: 1.02,
            transition: "easeOutQuad"
        });
        _tw.addTween(this.mask, {
            time: 0.1,
            scale: 1.02,
            transition: "easeOutQuad",
            onComplete: function (c) {
                _tw.addTween(c.center, {
                    time: 0.5,
                    scale: 1,
                    transition: "easeInOutBack"
                });
                _tw.addTween(c.centerBack, {
                    time: 0.55,
                    scale: 1,
                    transition: "easeInOutBack"
                });
                _tw.addTween(c.mask, {
                    time: 0.55,
                    scale: 1,
                    transition: "easeInOutBack"
                })
            },
            onCompleteParams: [this]
        });
        _tw.addTween(this.rh3, {
            time: 2,
            delay: b[0],
            scale: 4,
            opacity: 0,
            transition: "easeOutCubic"
        });
        _tw.addTween(this.yh3, {
            time: 2,
            delay: b[1],
            scale: 4,
            opacity: 0,
            transition: "easeOutCubic"
        });
        _tw.addTween(this.gh3, {
            time: 2,
            delay: b[2],
            scale: 4,
            opacity: 0,
            transition: "easeOutCubic"
        });
        _tw.addTween(this.ch3, {
            time: 0.2,
            delay: b[3],
            scale: 10,
            opacity: 1,
            transition: "linear",
            onComplete: function (c) {
                _tw.addTween(c.ch3, {
                    time: 0.25,
                    opacity: 0
                })
            },
            onCompleteParams: [this]
        });
        _tw.addTween(this.textGlow, {
            time: 10,
            delay: 0.5,
            scale: 120,
            opacity: 0.2,
            onComplete: function (c) {
                c.canvas.stop()
            },
            onCompleteParams: [this]
        })
    },
    mouseOut: function () {}
});
_iconController.initializeIcon("canvas-logo", ChromeLogo);
```