# Shine Icon/Image with canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I've been learning a bit about canvas and something that caught my attention (mostly because i had no idea how to do it when i saw) it's the shine and the nice animation that google did in their logo here:

http://www.google.com/chromebook/

I would like to know if someone have any idea or know how to do it =]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a shiny logo like Google Chromebooks website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387970/how-to-create-a-shiny-logo-like-google-chromebooks-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely see the other discussion here:

[How to create a shiny logo like Google Chromebooks website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387970/how-to-create-a-shiny-logo-like-google-chromebooks-website)

It wouldn't be hard to make yourself, simply consider having a canvas with an css `background-image` on it and all you need to do is start an animation on the `mouseover` event.

The animation draws a radial gradient with a radius that increases over time, then it draws a line that is affected by a linear gradient that moves from left to right.

If basic animation on the canvas itself is something new to you then I suggest you do a search for online tutorials about canvas animation.